# Disk size is variable

Tags: partition, dd, disk, hardware, lsblk

I was flashing a new operating system to a device, but after the process was complete, I couldn't boot into it. I then checked the disk, and I noticed something strange.

Different tools report different sizes for the disk, even though it should be approximately 120GB in size.

So, I decided to:

```bash
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

But the results were almost the same.

With `lsblk`:

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda            8:0    1 115.2G  0 disk
├─sda1         8:1    1   243M  0 part
└─sda2         8:2    1   2.2G  0 part
```

With `fdisk`:

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 7.66 GiB, 8225689600 bytes, 16065800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xaeaa381a
```

With `cfdisk`:

```bash
                          Disk: /dev/sda
        Size: 7.66 GiB, 8225689600 bytes, 16065800 sectors
                Label: dos, identifier: 0xaeaa381a

    Device      Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size  Id Type
>>  Free space          2048  16065799  16063752   7.7G
```

I didn't touch at the hardware. So the disk is probably still at ~120G.

What should I do to get the free space back ?

Comment: What is the make and model of the "device"?  You "flashed a new OS" onto the device, but I'm not familiar with disk devices that take full Operating Systems.  Was this more of an install of new firmware onto the device?

Comment: @SottoVoce I was flashing it to a PinePhone. I was previously using Arch on it, and wanted to try postmarketOS.

Comment: @telcoM Yes, I was writing a new image to it. The command that you wrote worked! I now see 113G of free space in cfdisk and I tried to flash it, and this time it worked :D
So it wasn't a hardware problem! Thank you for your answer and explanation :)
If you want to write this as an answer, I would mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "flashing a new operating system to a device", did you mean writing a complete disk image, including partition tables?

Note that your `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` should have certainly overwritten the DOS-type partition table, but if you did not trigger a rescan of the disk afterwards, the system will still be using the information from the old partition table.

As the cached partition table information also includes the size of the original disk the image was created from, it tricks the `fdisk` and `cfdisk` tools. On the other hand, `lsusb` looks at the actual size of the disk, ignoring the total size reported in the partition table.

Try `partprobe /dev/sda` if available, or `echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan` (both commands require root privileges).

If you needed to non-destructively update an existing partition table to e.g. recognize the full size of the disk after an imaging operation, the `growpart` tool might be the easiest way to do that.